# Select property from a link property in OrientDb

Tags: properties, orientdb

In OrientDB, I have a class "V_MyClass", and a property of type "link" to the class V_User ("createdBy"). Both extend V. 
In this moment, I have a query which returns all elements from class.

```
select from MyClass
```

"createdBy" is something like "#1:11". V_User has a property like "username". I want to add "username" for "createdBy", in this select.

The SQL version is:
- current query:

```
select * from MyClass
```

- requested query:

```
select m.*, u.username from myclass m inner join user u on m.createdBy = u.id
```

I want to reproduce the same query in OrientDB. Note that createdBy is not an edge, but a "link" property.

Comment: I do not know if I understand correctly, then would you create the username property on the link?

Comment: I don't want to create the username. In SQL standard, the query is something like "select u.username, m.* from my_class m inner join user u on [...]" I want only to extract username from V_User in the select.

Comment: I edited my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use this query

```
select *,createdBy.username from V_MyClass
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, works. Works also your js function with the script for populate some vertices, from my last question (it seems to be deleted now)

Comment: If my answer is correct, could you select my answer as best, please?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add properties to the relationship you will need to do an update (it is not a normal query). If you do a "selec...from...where..." you won't update.

Try with this (you can see more info in the doc):

```
UPDATE <class>|cluster:<cluster>|<recordID>
[SET|INCREMENT|ADD|REMOVE|PUT <field-name> = <field-value>[,]*]|[CONTENT|MERGE <JSON>]
[UPSERT]
[RETURN <returning> [<returning-expression>]]
[WHERE <conditions>]
[LOCK default|record]
[LIMIT <max-records>] [TIMEOUT <timeout>]
```

Comment: I need only to extract a property from the user, which I need on java side. I don't think it is the best idea to update the database.

Comment: but u said this: I want to add "username" for "createdBy", in this select. In a select you can't do an update

Comment: I edited my question, I hope I am more explicit now.